# 404 error when using https with signalR

Tags: https, signalr

I am using signalR over https and I have seeming done everything off this site:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Sep/23/Hosting-SignalR-under-SSLhttps

Yet, I am still getting a 404 error when I signalr is trying to connect.

```
https://localhost:9000//negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22logshub%22%7D%5D&_=1438785507850 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my OWIN startup program starting on https://*:9000

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dbFile = "logDB.sqlite";

        if (!File.Exists(dbFile))
        {
            SQLiteDataProviderCreator.Create();
            SQLiteDataProviderCreator.CreateDataBase();
        }

        IDataProvider provider = new SQLiteDataProvider("Data Source=logdb.sqlite;Version=3;PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;");

        LogsModule.Provider = provider;

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("https://*:9000/"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Launched site on Port 9000");
            Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to quit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And here the javascript that is supposed to allow it to connect over https.

```
    var hubUrl = "https://localhost:9000/signalr";
    $.connection.hub.url = hubUrl;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
```

I also created a cert using makecert and bound it to the endpoint 0.0.0.0:9000.

Comment: I would assume the URL should be `https://localhost:9000/signalr/negotiate..` (notice `signalr` before `negotiate?...`)`

Comment: Definitely tried hardcoding in that. Unfortunately did not work...

Comment: Do you get 404 in both cases if you try invoke it manually (from a browser)? Anyways, I think you need to show some code...

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where I had to run the program as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this.
The hubUrl should normally be:

var hubUrl = "https://localhost:9000/signalr/hubs";

This is even shown in the link provided.

Also, needs to ensure that the hub script is loaded prior to this script:

```
  <script src='https://localhost:9000/signalr/hubs'></script>
```